# Is there any way to convert python set to be used in SQL's "IN" statement?

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

I am trying to make an SQL statement that updates multiple rows with set of keys. I do realize that I could just run for each with statement for every single key, but this seems like "more correct" and much faster for me.

This is what I've got:

```
    def end_actions(self, timestamp, ids):
         statement = "UPDATE items " \
                "SET end_time = " + timestamp + " " \
                "WHERE auction IN " + ids + ";"
        self.execute_statement(statement)
```

question is how do I format IDs set to be accepted by SQL's IN statement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what type your IDs are. I'll assume it's a set of integers. You want the SQL clause to look something like this `WHERE auction IN (1, 2, 3);`. So you can `map` your set to a list of strings and pass it to `join` with a comma separator and wrap it in parentheses.

```
"WHERE auction IN (" + ", ".join(map(str, ids)) + ");"
```

EDIT: If instead you want strings, you might need to wrap it in quotes first

```
"WHERE auction IN (" + ", ".join("'" + id + "'" for id in ids) + ");"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, did not realize that python has a map function, should work well.